# Почему если в исходном массиве, если последний элемент == 1 не добавляет в новую коллекцию?

Tags: c#

Есть массив из нулей и единиц, мне нужно за один проход по массиву найти сумму единиц до каждого из нулей и результат записать в новую коллекцию, проблема в том, что в новую коллекцию не добавляется последний элемент, как мне это исправить? Спасибо.

```
const int N = 10;
int[] array = new int[N];
Random random = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        array[i] = random.Next(2);
Console.WriteLine("Исходный массив: " + string.Join(", ", array));
int sum = 0;
var list = new List<int>();    
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) {
    if (array[i] == 1) {
        sum = sum + 1;
    } else if (array[i] == 0) {
        if (sum != 0) {
            list.Add(sum);
        }
        sum = 0;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("Результирующий массив: " + string.Join(",", list));
```

Comment: т.е. количество элементов в результирующей коллекции должно совпадать с количеством нулей в исходном массиве и каждый элемент равен сумме единиц до соответствующего нуля, я правильно понял текст "найти сумму единиц до каждого из нулей и результат записать в новую коллекцию"? Просто если я правильно понял текст, то вы неправильно обрабатываете проход нуля и вместо суммы до каждого нуля, считаете суммы непрерывных групп из единиц.

Comment: Мне нужна сумма подряд встречающихся единиц до первого встречного нуля

Comment: Ну так так и напишите, чтобы других с толку не сбивало. А то в вопросе одно, в коде другое, не хорошо как-то

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, после окончания цикла сделать еще раз:

```
for ( ... ) {
    ...
}
if (sum != 0) {
    list.Add(sum);
}
```

Еще один вариант - добавить принудительно в массив завершающий 0:

```
int[] array = new int[N + 1];
...
for ( ... )
    ...
array[N] = 0;
```

ну и, наконец, можно вместо явного добавления нуля в массив добавить его в перебираемую последовательность, если вы используете .NET 4.7.1 или выше - с помощью метода-расширения [`Enumerable.Append`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt823360(v=vs.110).aspx) (придется заменить цикл `for` на `foreach`):

```
foreach (int x in array.Append(0)) {
    if (x == 1) {
        sum = sum + 1;
    } else if (x == 0) {
        if (sum != 0) {
            list.Add(sum);
        }
        sum = 0;
    }
}
```

В более ранних версиях .NET вместо `Append` можно использовать `Concat` (но это не так удобно - придется заводить массив с одним нулем):

```
foreach (int x in array.Concat(new[] { 0 }))
```

Comment: Здорово, спасибо большое!) Кстати, есть ли какие-нибудь замечания по коду?

Comment: @Cerej, добавил еще пару способов. Код вроде нормальный, особо придраться не к чему